# What impact does UseMicrosoftUpdate have on the UpdateSource option when installing SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, installation

The `ConfigurationFile.ini` generated for SQL Server 2014 contains a new parameter that I cannot find documented anywhere - `UseMicrosoftUpdate`.

What impact does this parameter have on the `UpdateSource` and `UpdateEnabled` parameters?

Comment: I use `UpdateSource` when I'm first installing an instance of SQL Server to slipstream service packs and cumulative updates that I've previously downloaded. It's a quick way to ensure the instance is up-to-date when it first starts. I'd never use `UseMicrosoftUpdate` on a server, but it can be useful on a workstation so that SQL Server receives security patches along with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UseMicrosoftUpdate` - Setting it to `TRUE` - it will change the computer settings to include the latest updates when you scan for Windows Update.

I would suggest to set it `FALSE` and you decide what updates you want for SQL Server in-terms of SPs/CUs.

From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638066.aspx) :

> **UpdateEnabled** - Specify whether SQL Server setup should discover and include product updates. The valid values are `True` and `False` or 1 and 0. **By default, SQL Server setup will include updates that are found.**
>
> **UpdateSource** - Specify the location where SQL Server setup will obtain product updates. The valid values are "MU" to search Microsoft Update, a valid folder path, a relative path such as `.\MyUpdates` or a `UNC share`. By default, SQL Server setup will search Microsoft Update or a Windows Update Service through the Windows Server Update Services

So the `UseMicrosoftUpdate` is more of a **global** thing governed as part of windows update vs `UpdateEnabled` is governed only during sql server installation/setup and `UpdateSource` is the location that will have sql server update files. Thats my understanding.

Honestly, I will not even enable any of those, since any SP/CU has to be regression tested and [lately there are many problems](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/team-posts/latest-builds-sql-server-2014/) with SP/CUs that can screw up many things. They are addressed with subsequent hotfixes.

With introduction of SQL Server 2016, [Microsoft has made changes to their Incremental Servicing Model (ISM)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-updates-to-the-sql-server-incremental-servicing-model-ism/)

> As of January CU releases, we now recommend ongoing, proactive installation of CU’s as they become available. You should plan to install a CU with the same level of confidence you plan to install SPs (Service Packs) as they are released. This is because CU’s are certified and tested to the level of SP’s.